# Is identifying the range of function necessary?

Tags: functions

I often see functions written as $f:\Bbb{R}\rightarrow\Bbb{R}$ or similarly $f:\Bbb{C}\rightarrow\Bbb{C}$.

My concern is that there are functions where $f:\Bbb{R}\rightarrow\Bbb{R}$ doesn't satisfy.
And the more specific the function gets, the more likely it doesn't map to just basic number system (Such as reals, or complex).

So why are we stating: $$f:\Bbb{Domain}\rightarrow\Bbb{Codomain}$$

and deal with it from there?

Wouldn't it be better if we just state the domain (Like $f:\Bbb{R}\rightarrow$) and discuss about how range depends on the condition we are given? I don't see what the big deal of setting codomain is.

I feel like I might be missing something basic from this question.

Thank you for your help in advance!

Comment: One advantage is that we would not readily find out whether $f\colon A\to$ can be composed with $g\colon B\to$

Comment: Let's say that $f\colon\mathbb R\to $ is given by $f(t)=(t,t)$. Where does $(t,t)$ live, in $\mathbb R^2$ or $\mathbb C$? Compare $f(1)^2$ in $\mathbb R^2$ with $f(1)^2$ in $\mathbb C$.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen But even if we set codomain and know composition is possible for such two functions, from there, we are only building assumptions on top of assumptions and so on. Wouldn't it be better to just say be more strong on statement and use f mapping to range and g has a domain of range(f) (or set that include range of f)? I guess my question is why Codomain not range.

Comment: @RandyMarsh I guess first question is R^2 but I don't know what f(x)^2 in this context. But we can find answer to these questions after computing or investigating the function f. So why are we being so loose on setting mapping of function to it's codomain?

Comment: Well $f(x)^2 = f(x) \cdot f(x)$, so $f(1)^2=(1,1)\cdot (1,1)$. The point is that when you think of $(x,y)$ as an element $\mathbb R^2$, then $f(1)^2 = (1,1)\cdot (1,1) = (1,1)$. But when you think of $(x,y)$ as an element of $\mathbb C$, then $f(1)^2 = (1,1)\cdot (1,1) = (0,2)$. There isn't enough information in $f\colon \mathbb R\to$, $f(x)=(x,x)$ to tell you which of the two options above is correct.

Comment: @RandyMarsh Thanks for the reply. Well, shouldn't it be defined as f: C -> in the second example? Then it makes sense that f(1)^2 = (0,2). I guess we don't know if (0,2) is real, complex or what it is but this can be depended also on context again right? So I still don't see why codomain is necessary.

Comment: Changing codomain can change important properties of the function. For example $f(x)=x^2$ is not surjective from $\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ but it is surjective if $\mathbb{R} \to [0,\infty)$.

Comment: Well if I want a function that takes only real numbers as input and nothing else, then I can't define it on $\mathbb C$. For example, functions of type $f\colon[0,1]\to Y$ where $Y$ doesn't necessarily have anything to do with $\mathbb R$ are very common in mathematics, they're called *paths on* $Y$. So, if I want a function to take only real numbers as input, I need some information about where the output lives to be able to even define the function properly. As you can see with $f(x)^2$, specifying the mapping rule isn't enough, because the rule behaves differently in different codomains.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want to know why it is “helpful” or “intuitive” for a function to have a codomain.

Just to be clear (I don’t think this is what you’re asking about), it’s not possible to make a function with *no idea* of what the codomain is. How could you specify a rule for computing the function without giving a way the type of thing that rule produces? Even worse, how could you check to make sure that the function maps each input to a unique output in the codomain?

On the other hand, some function rules are so closely related that we use the same notation, even when the domain (and codomain) are different: $x \to 2x$, or $x \to e^{x}$, for example. They both work on integers, reals, even square matrices. Why isn’t there some way to define these rules less strictly, so we can study them without specifying exactly what the domain/codomain are?

First of all, there *is* a way: “$2x$” is a polynomial, “$e^{x}$” can be written as a power series, and both of these are mathematical objects that can be studied without referencing a specific function with a specific domain.

On the other hand, lots of math is basically trying to answer the question “what happens when we extend this type of function to a larger domain?” Examples include analytic continuation in complex analysis, the theory of field extensions, etc. The function $x^2 + 1$ is pretty simple, but it has roots in $\mathbb{C}$ but not $\mathbb{R}$. Also, there are tons of important math questions that boil down to “does a function exist from $X$ to $Y$?” In these cases it’s obviously important to know the domain/codomain.

So to sum up, we need the domain and codomain to define the function rule at all; once the function is defined, it’s often directly relevant to our question; and if it isn’t, we can probably use other objects.

Comment: I see. I already asked this in the other answer. (that is deleted now) So codomain really is just Deus Ex Machina to where element of domain will be mapped to. Am I correct? This is what threw me off because codomain feels like it's just saying the element gets mapped to somewhere.

Comment: If $f : X \to Y$, that does not mean the $f(x)$ fill up *all of* $Y$. (When they do it is a special type of function called a surjection). The statement $f : X \to Y$ simply means “$f$ maps each element of $X$ to somewhere in $Y$,” it doesn’t specify where.

Comment: What are the reasons why we define function’s domain mapping to codomain instead of range? Is it because range is often difficult to talk about?

Comment: To define a function $f : X \to Y$ we just need to show that no $x$ maps to more than one $y$. Showing that the $x$ map to all of $Y$ is sometimes pretty trivial, but other times hard, and in any case it’s definitely more work.